# How to get list banned ip and its unban time in fail2ban on Linux?

Tags: linux, iptables, fail2ban

how to see a list of banned ip addresses and get its unban time? I know two methods to get list banned ip addresses.

Via fail2ban client:

```
sudo fail2ban-client status <jail name>
```

Via iptables:

```
sudo iptables --list --line-numbers --numeric
```

But both commands show only ban list. I need to know when this created iptables rules will be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

1. Fail2ban since version 0.11.1 supports new command which would provide you the list of banned-IPs and its times, see man or https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/2315#issuecomment-451779004 for details.
2. Otherwise fail2ban since version 0.9 has a sqlite-database where you also could obtain this information:

```bsh
sqlite3 -header -column 'file:/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3?mode=ro' \
"select * from bans where jail='<JAIL>' order by timeofban desc limit 10"
```

For instance this could be the statement to get all active bans:

```sql
select datetime(timeofban, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as startofban, 
datetime(timeofban + bantime, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as endofban,
ip, jail, bantime, bancount, data from bips
where endofban > datetime('now', 'localtime')
order by jail, endofban
limit 10
```

Depending on version it can miss `bantime` field, then you have to replace it with static integer bantime set for the related jail in your configuration.

3. If you have some development background, it would be also possible using fail2ban python API

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see banned ips unban time and some other information

```
while true; do
  # Clear the terminal
  clear

  # Display static header
  echo -e "\e[1;44m        List of Banned IPs         \n\e[0m"

  # Fetch dynamic info
  IPs=$(sudo fail2ban-client status sshd | grep "Banned IP list:" | sed 's/.*Banned IP list://g' | tr -s ' ' '\n')
  current_count=$(echo -e "$IPs" | wc -l)
  total_count=$(grep "Ban " /var/log/fail2ban.log | wc -l)

  # Display Currently Banned IPs and Total Banned to Date
  echo -e "\e[1;32m   Currently Banned IPs: $current_count\e[0m"
  echo -e "\e[1;32m   Total Banned to Date: $total_count\n\e[0m"
  

  # Display table headers
  echo -e " ┌─────┬──────────────────────┬───────────┐"
  echo -e " │ No. │          IP          │  Unban In │"
  echo -e " ├─────┼──────────────────────┼───────────┤"

  # Parse each IP and look up its ban time in the log file
  echo -e "$IPs" | awk '{print NR, $1}' | while read -r num ip; do
    ban_time=$(grep "$ip" /var/log/fail2ban.log | tail -1 | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' | xargs -I {} date -d {} +%s)
    current_time=$(date +%s)
    time_left=$(( 3600 - (current_time - ban_time) ))
    mins=$(( (time_left + 59) / 60 ))
    [ $mins -eq 0 ] && mins=1
    printf " │ %2d  │     %-15s  │%4d mins  │\n" "$num" "$ip" "$mins"
    
  done
echo " └─────┴──────────────────────┴───────────┘"  # Line below each IP
  counter=0
  server_info=""

  for i in {59..0}; do
    if ((counter % 10 == 0)); then
      cpu_temp=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp 2>/dev/null)
      cpu_load=$(uptime | awk -F 'load average: ' '{print $2}')
      disk_usage=$(df -h / | awk 'NR==2 {print $5}')
      memory_usage=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2 {print $3 "/" $2 "MB"}')
      logged_users=$(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l)
      logged_users_list=$(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ', ' | sed 's/,$//')
      cpu_temp_c=$(awk -v temp="$cpu_temp" 'BEGIN{printf "%.1f", temp / 1000}')


      server_info="\e[1;32m\n - Server Info:\n - CPU Load : $cpu_load\n - CPU Temp : $cpu_temp_c °C\n - Disk Usage : $disk_usage\n - Memory Usage : $memory_usage\n - Count of unique logged-in users : $logged_users\n - Logged in as : $logged_users_list\n\e[0m"
    fi

    echo -e "\e[1;32m  Current Time: $(date '+%H:%M:%S')\e[0m"
    echo " ──────────────────────────────────────────"
    echo -e "$server_info"
    echo " ──────────────────────────────────────────"
    counter=$((counter + 1))
    sleep 1

    # Clear the lines for server info and time, but no more than that
    echo -ne "\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A"
  done
done
```